# How to code in UE4 using Visual Studio only?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

After some time I had in mind to try Unreal Engine beside Unity (look how to code, how to solve things here with help of C++ and the UE API). A unresolving problem is IntelliSense in Visual Studio without any 3rd party tools like Visual Assist or Resharper C++ (which is the only good supported IDE for UE4). When adding a new `#include` in the header section, IntelliSense underlines line 10 `UCLASS()` red, because `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`. Take this header file as an example:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h" // Broken when adding this line
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "RotatingActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class UE419DEMO_API ARotatingActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY() // ERROR: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

public: 
    ARotatingActor();

protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UStaticMeshComponent *StaticMeshComponent; // The include is needed for this line here, because without the header file, IntelliSense doesn't autocomplete methods which belong to this class.

};
```

This file compiles perfectly fine without any build errors on any side of Visual Studio, despite the red underlined `UCLASS()` and red lines on the `.cpp` side because `class "UObject" has no member "BeginPlay"`. This is disrupting in some way, because this error isn't a real error, rather a error because Visual Studio can't recognize the macro `UCLASS()`, which previously was on line 9 and now on line 10.

That said I ask me if this behavior is normal. Do I have to pay money (Visual Assist) or keep reopening Visual Studio (which disrupts my coding flow and also steals time) to solve that problem. Does somebody has a solution for this specific problem?

Comment: "There are build errors" means your code doesn't compile - this isn't IntelliSense's fault and third party tools won't fix it either. Read the error messages and fix those errors instead of blaming your tools

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it right, it sais that it is expecting to have build errors because of the false placed macro. I'm not that of a noob to not recognize my build errors in that file.

Comment: No, that message still means that your code failed to compile - this has nothing to do with IntelliSense. In fact the full message asks you if you want to run *the last successful build*. There's an Error list available in Visual studio that will list all the errors that occurred during compilation

Comment: First stop downvoting without reason, it **does** compile: `========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: I used to run into many of these issues, but do not remember the specific steps I used to fix them. FWIW, I do have a C++ project (with some blueprints on top, but those are minimal configuration differences) working with just UE4.18 & VS2017.

Comment: The errors persist, just this bizarre build error dialog disappeared.

Comment: Hmm, reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote I think that downvoting answers which seem stupid is actually the idea of the voting mechanism. After all "stupid" is practically the opposite of "helpful". This also applies in case you should actually refer to downvoting questions which seem stupid.

Comment: So I'm not allowed to ask a question where no answer was given at any time?

Comment: I do not understand that. Apart from its provocative nature of course. What do you mean by "a question where no answer was given at any time"?

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes, personally. If I had to guess, I'd think the language of your post comes across as a bit fussy, and maybe that's rubbing people the wrong way? I'd also suggest also posting this on the [UE4 Q/A](https://answers.unrealengine.com/).

Comment: Because I'm fighting with this for about a year right now and I'm a bit sick of it. I already posted this on the UE4 Q/A but nobody got an answer for half a year. That's why I posted the question with the risk of being downvoted (what clearly happened here).

Comment: @alexanders916: People are downvoting because half the question is a rant, and the problem is very poorly described to the point where it's hard for us to even understand what you're experiencing. You mention intellisense, but then also quote build errors, but then also say that there are no build errors. You say intellisense throws up because the macro isn't on line 9, but don't say what "throw up" means, or describe why line 9 is relevant. This confusion means the question is unclear, which means it should be downvoted.

Comment: However: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/299013/uclass-error.html looks similar, and https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/118541-this-declaration-has-no-storage-class-or-type-specifier. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RxCompiLe.UE4Intellisense appears to be a plugin designed to help.

Comment: Ok I will rewrite my question in a proper way and language, I'm sorry, I'm just angry that this can't be fixed...

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  There's no reason to mention `RotationSpeed` in your stackoverflow question.

Comment: @MooingDuck To your solutions... I already looked them up. The first one is the "recompile another solution" workaround and the other is Visual Assist which costs 100$.

Comment: @alexanders916: The question reads MUCH better now, thanks you. Changed my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal in my experience. I have followed instructions to set up VS and I still get underlines. Now I just ignore them.